# What defines speed of ffmpeg command execution?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, amazon-web-services

Which factors contribute or contribute the most to ffmpeg commands?

- Video duration
- Video Size
- Video Format (mp4, mov etc)
- Video Resolution

I'm performing different operations on videos e.g. overlaying and image over a video, overlaying text, converting other formats (like mov, webm etc) to mp4 aka transcoding. I wanted to know what contributes the most in defining the speed of execution. I want to compute the price of running on an AWS lambda function. The pricing depends upon the execution time. I've allocated the max memory and computer power to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making cuts to a video if you use the -ss switch to go to the right time it goes way faster. If you have to render the video like converting to a different codec it also takes longer rather than using the -c:v copy switch but if you make any changes to the video like using filters to modify the video you have to do a new rendering anyway witch can take a long time depending on:

- length of video
- resolution
- Frames per second
- video quality

Comment: what is the difference between resolution and quality? By quality do you mean video size?

Comment: Resolution is the size of the video frames that you can set by -s or with video filter -vf "scale=720:-1" for example 720 and whatever the proportional hight is...quality is set with -q 80 for exemple it varies from 0 to 100, setting the quality lower can result in smaller size but video may lose nitidy or get blury..